# Add a possibility for zero optional inputs to own command

Tags: macros, sectioning, numbering, optional-arguments

Some very nice people here helped me write the code snippet below. And the code works great
it prints out the correct subtext, and have a optional argument by typing `*`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcounter{problem}
\setcounter{problem}{0}
\newcounter{alternative}
\setcounter{alternative}{0}
\newif\iffirstalt
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Oppgave}{s m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
     {\stepcounter{alternative}\iffirstalt\else\stepcounter{problem}\firstalttrue\fi}%
     {\setcounter{alternative}{0}\stepcounter{problem}\firstaltfalse}%
  \section*{Oppgave \arabic{problem}%
             {\normalfont\IfBooleanTF{#1}{~Alternative \Roman{alternative}\ }{}
                \normalsize (#2 poeng)}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Oppgave \arabic{problem} }} 
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\oppgaveS{3}

\oppgaveS{4}

\oppgaveS*{2}

\oppgaveS*{2}

\oppgaveS{3}

\oppgaveS*{2}

\end{document}
```

Is there any possibility to add zero optional inputs? I mean so that i can write

```
\Oppgave and \Oppgave*
```

To be displayed as

**Oppgave 1** and **Oppgave 1 Alternativ 1**

I just want to have no small text, if I just plainly write the command =)

Comment: Do you mean 1 optional parameter? If so you can use `[1][<default>]` to specify that the first parameter of a `\newcommand` as optional. Or use the `o`, `O` type parameter with `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: Note that your MWE does not compile and uses `\Oppgave` while `\oppgaveS` is the defined command.

Comment: @Werner: I assumed that `\oppgaveS` was intended to be the new version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example with default TeX syntax and without the xparse package which is already more for package developers than for users with local macros:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcounter{problem}
\newcounter{alternative}
\newif\iffirstalt

\makeatletter
\def\Oppgave{\@ifnextchar*{\Oppgave@i}{\Oppgave@ii}}
\def\Oppgave@i*{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\Oppgave@iii}{\Oppgave*{1}}}
\def\Oppgave@ii{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\Oppgave@iv}{\Oppgave{1}}}
\def\Oppgave@iii#1{%
  \setcounter{alternative}{0}\stepcounter{problem}\firstaltfalse
  \section*{Oppgave \arabic{problem}%
             \normalfont~Alternative \Roman{alternative}\ \normalsize (#1 poeng)}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Oppgave \arabic{problem} }} 
\def\Oppgave@iv#1{\stepcounter{alternative}\iffirstalt\else\stepcounter{problem}\firstalttrue\fi
  \section*{Oppgave \arabic{problem} \normalsize (#1 poeng)}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Oppgave \arabic{problem} }} 
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\Oppgave{3}    
\Oppgave{4}
\Oppgave*{2}
\Oppgave*{2}
\Oppgave{3}
\Oppgave*{2}
\Oppgave
\Oppgave*
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The following requires a small modification to your input. Instead of using `\oppgaveS*{<num>}`, use `\oppgaveS*[<num>]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcounter{problem} %\setcounter{problem}{0}
\newcounter{alternative} %\setcounter{alternative}{0}
\newif\iffirstalt
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse

\NewDocumentCommand{\oppgaveS}{s o}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
   {\stepcounter{alternative}\iffirstalt\else\stepcounter{problem}\firstalttrue\fi}%
   {\setcounter{alternative}{0}\stepcounter{problem}\firstaltfalse}%
  \section*{Oppgave~\arabic{problem}~%
    {\normalfont\IfBooleanTF{#1}{Alternative \Roman{alternative}~}{}}%
                \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\normalfont\normalsize (#2 poeng)}}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Oppgave~\arabic{problem}} 
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\oppgaveS[3]
\oppgaveS[4]
\oppgaveS*[2]
\oppgaveS*[2]
\oppgaveS[3]
\oppgaveS*[2]
\oppgaveS*
\oppgaveS*[3]
\oppgaveS
\oppgaveS
\oppgaveS*
\end{document}
```

The optional argument specification `o` from [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) takes the value `\NoValue` if it is empty (when using `\oppgaveS` or `\oppgaveS*`), and conditioned upon using `\IfNoValueTF`.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the argument as optional by changing the first line of the definition into

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Oppgave}{s g}{%
```

You have to change also `\normalsize (#2 poeng)` into

```
\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\ \normalsize (#2 poeng)}
```

deleting `\` (control space) in the line before.

On the other hand it would be clearer if you adopted the syntax

```
\Oppgave*[n]
```

(simply change the "g" in the argument to `\NewDocumentCommand` to an "o").

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\oppgaveS}{s g}{% Put o instead of g for clearer syntax
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
   {\stepcounter{alternative}\iffirstalt\else\stepcounter{problem}\firstalttrue\fi}%
   {\setcounter{alternative}{0}\stepcounter{problem}\firstaltfalse}%
  \section*{Oppgave~\arabic{problem}%
    {\normalfont\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\ Alternative \Roman{alternative}}{}}%
                \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\ \normalfont\normalsize (#2 poeng)}}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Oppgave~\arabic{problem}} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to say `\Oppgave` and that should be the same as `\Oppgave{1}` and `\Oppgave*` to be the same as `\Oppgave*{1}`

If so, you can just replace the line

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Oppgave}{s m}{%
```

with

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Oppgave}{s O{1}}{%
```

Then the first parameter (`#2` since the `s` represents a `*` which is considered `#1`) is optional and will take on a value of `{1}` if not specified.  The portion with the `{}` is the default value if a parameter is not specified.

From [the `xparse` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse), you can define optional arguments with either a lower case `o`, or an upper case `O`:

> `o` A standard LaTeX optional argument, surrounded with square brackets, which will
>   supply the special `\NoValue` token if not given.
>
> `O` As for `o`, but returns `{default}` if no value is given. Should be given as `O{default}`.

if you want to be able to use `{}` for the optional args you should use

> `g` An optional argument given inside a pair of TEX group tokens (in standard LATEX, `{}`), which returns `\NoValue` if not present.
>
> `G` As for g but returns `default` if no value is given: `G{default`}`.

The MWE you provided was using the `m` option which is documented as:

> `m` A standard mandatory argument, which can either be a single token alone or multiple tokens surrounded by curly braces. Regardless of the input, the argument will be passed to the internal code surrounded by a brace pair. This is the xparse type specifier for a normal TEX argument.

Comment: I've changed the reference from xstrings to xparse